# Partially Solved : Excel Simple Edits to Path

Tags: excel, path, excel-2013

I create new Excel workbook monthly that refers to another Excel workbook(similar but different).
In the new workbook (say June 14.xlsx) it has many cells that refer to the old workbook.
So in the New Workbook you may find references such as ''C:\Users\user\Desktop[Template - May 14.xlsx]Sheet1''!$A$1.
A quick Find and Replace in formulas allows me to change the path [Template - April 14.xlsx] to  [Template - May 14.xlsx] and the references refresh and bring the relevant data perfectly.

I would like to not use the Find and Replace and do the way one would when doing Object Oriented Programming and have the ''C:\Users\user\Desktop[Template - May 14.xlsx]'' to a single cell or 'name manager' so that I only need to change at only one position/location.

Name Manager, Hyperlink, Reference a cell containing the path? 
All solutions welcomed.

Comment: any thing that you have tried so far?

Comment: With the whole path plus book,sheet and cell reference in Name Manager this pulls the data correctly.
However having under name manager ="C:\Users\user\Desktop\[Template - May 14.xlsx]" is fine but I am not being able to add the reference to the sheet and cell while on the cell that will receive the values. 
Any luck (or expertise) anyone?

Comment: Any way forward on this? 
I have seen this on Power Query. perhaps there is something similar
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath&FileName))
Just musing.

Comment: INDIRECT seems to work and a good option but it requires the files to be open.
=INDIRECT("'["&C2&"]"&C4&"'!"&C5) or =INDIRECT("'["&C2&"]"&C4&"'!$D$5")
with dedicated cells on C2, C4.
Any thoughts on a solution that would work irrespective with the files open and closed.